# Sum cells within row range of merged cell in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I am trying to setup an automatic formula that would sum values. Specifically the formula needs to sum all cells in a row that falls within a merged cell.

The scenario is quite simple, I have an order that can have multiple items within. Items have some unique info like title and price but also some common values like order id and order total. The common fields are merged to make it clear and prevent double summing of values in a row.

How would I get the cells that fall withing a merged row? I am open to any other ideas if there is a better way to achieve order tracking I outlined.

Sample data:

```
------------------------------------------------------
Order-ID     Title         Price      Order-Price
------------------------------------------------------
1            product 1     4.5        
            -------------------------
1            product 2     1.5         6.0
------------------------------------------------------
2            product 1     5           5
------------------------------------------------------
```

Order-ID and Order-Price are merged cells as the data is common. Order-Price should automatically sum Price from the cells in the same row range. This is just the way I am thinking of doing this but there could certainly be better ways of achieving similar results.

Comment: show some sample data, and an idea of what it will look like as an output

Comment: @PeterH I added sample data to the original question.